# Use of uninitialized value and Illegal division

Tags: perl

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $cxsorted[-1] in division (/) at /scratch/mauve_pro/Bordetella_species/src/cdhit.hist-plot.pl line 58, <IN> line 53.
Illegal division by zero at /scratch/mauve_pro/Bordetella_species/src/cdhit.hist-plot.pl line 58, <IN> line 53.
```

Este es el script y esta es el código de la linea problema:

```
my$m = 10 / $cxsorted[-1];
```

**código completo**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use File::Basename;
use Statistics::R;


&GetOptions(    'in=s' => \my$inlist,       #
        'density' => \my$densplot,
        'out=s' => \my$out);        #
($inlist and $out) or &HELP_MESSAGE;

my$ind=1;
my@xcoord=();
my@ycoord=();
my@cx=();
my@genomes=();
my@ticks=();
my@dens1=();
my@dens2=();

open IN, "$inlist";
while(my$i = <IN>){
    chomp$i;
    my$name = basename($i);
    $name =~ s/\.out[\w\W]+$//g;
    push(@genomes, $name);
    push(@ticks, $ind);
    #print join("\t", ($i,$name,$ind))."\n";

    open HIST, "$i";
    while(my$hist = <HIST>){
        chomp$hist;
        if($hist =~ /^\d/){
            my@sh = split("\t",$hist);

            if($sh[1] > 0){
                for(my$d=0; $d<$sh[2]; $d++){
                    push(@dens1, $name);
                    push(@dens2, $sh[0]);
                }

                if($sh[0] > 1){
                    #print join("\t",($name,$ind,$sh[0],$sh[2]))."\n";
                    push(@xcoord, $ind);
                    push(@ycoord, $sh[0]);
                    push(@cx, $sh[2]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $ind++;
}

#set largest value to 10, scale other values accordingly
my@cxsorted = sort{$a <=> $b}@cx; 
#print $cxsorted[-1]."\n";
my$m = 10 / $cxsorted[-1];
#print $m * $cxsorted[-1]."\n";
foreach my$x (@cx) { $x = $x * $m; };
for(my$ww = 0; $ww < scalar(@dens1); $ww++){
    #print $dens1[$ww]."\t".$dens2[$ww]."\n";
}

my$R = Statistics::R->new();
if($densplot){
    $R->run( qq' library(ggplot2) ' );
    $R->set('d1', \@dens1 );
    $R->set('d2', \@dens2 );
    $R->run( qq' dd <- data.frame(d1,d2) ');
    #my$dfhead = $R->get( qq' colnames(dd[1]) ');
    #my$ddclass = $R->get( qq' class(dd) ');

    #print $dfhead."\t".$ddclass."\n";
    $R->run( qq' png("$out",width=1400,height=800,pointsize=14) ');
    $R->run( qq' qplot( d2, data = dd, geom = "density" , fill=d1, alpha=.2,adjust=0.05) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,200,5)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,0.15),xlim=c(3,70)) ');
    $R->run( qq' dev.off() ' );
}else{
    $R->set('ind', \@xcoord );
    $R->set('counts', \@ycoord );
    $R->set('diam', \@cx );
    $R->set('genomes', \@genomes );
    $R->set('ttt', \@ticks );
    $R->run( qq' png("$out",width=1000,height=800,pointsize=14) ');
    $R->run( qq' plot(ind, counts, type="p",pch=21,bg=rgb(0,1,0,0.3), cex=diam, xlab="Genome index", ylab="Gene occurance (>1)",main = "CDHIT-est", xaxt ="n") ');
    $R->run( qq' axis(side=1, at=ttt, tck=-0.02) ' );
    $R->run( qq' dev.off() ' );
}



sub HELP_MESSAGE { die "
.Description:
   Takes set of cdhit cluster distribution files from cdhit.plot_len.pl and draws a simple plot.
.Usage: $0 -in [in.txt] -out [out.png]
   [mandatory]
     -in    <in.txt>    List of paths to cluster distribution files.
     -out   <out.png>   Output image file of plot.
   [optional]
     -density       Make density plot using 'ggplot2'.
   [dependencies]
     R (Statistics::R, ggplot2)
" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende en el archivo de "in", el máximo de la tercer columna del archivo es 0 (cuando la primera es mas de 1 y la segunda es positiva) o no hay datos en el archivo.  Para saber, saca el # en la secunda linea de `print` como

```perl
print join("\t", $name, $ind, $sh[0], $sh[2]) . "\n";
```

y tal vez

```perl
print join(", ", @cxsorted) . "\n";
```

antes de línea 53